# Help Identifying a Capacitor (R1C 332 and KDP 109)

Tags: capacitor, identification, capacitance, markings

I've been looking through the various posts on capacitors and doing some research on identifying capacitors and haven't found anything that quite fits my situation. I have a very small ceramic capacitor from the power supply side of a subwoofer amp that I believe may be dead as some of the nearby components are also not reading correct values.

This capacitor has two sets of markings, one on either side. The following is what I've been able to make out for how small it is: R1C 332 and KDP 109

From what I've read 109 might be 10000000000 pF, but also 332 might be 3300pF.
I've also read that 1C = 16V, but maybe R1C means 0.16V since R can mean a decimal?
I'm not really finding much on KDP (although that D looks a little off)

Also, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of a polarity on this capacitor, other than tracing the circuit it came from to find the ground is there a way to tell by looking at it which way the capacitor is polarized?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's a 3300pF ceramic unpolarized capacitor.

Probably 50V.

Probably manufactured in 2010 week 9.

Can't tell the dielectric but 3300pF in a small size package is probably going to be X7S

Answer (score 1):

That's a ceramic cap, they are non polarised, and I would bet 3300pF and not 10^10pF which would definitely be a very large electrolytic.

It is most probably fine, they are reliable as parts go and nearly never the first place to look for a failure.